# Codeigniter: Why does tank use InnoDB instead of MyISAM?

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I installed Tank_Auth and saw that it's using InnoDB while my tables are all using MyISAM. Will this be a problem? Should I change it to MyISAM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - InnoDB vs MyISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251179/mysql-innodb-vs-myisam)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be left InnoDB, which supports foreign key relationships.  MyISAM is easy to port to InnoDB, but not vice versa.